# Create a cell array in matlab

Tags: regex, arrays, matlab, twitter, cell

I have a file of tweets that I have read into matlab using `dataread` and I have stored each line into a 30x1 cell.  I was wondering if there was a to take each hashtag out and store them in their own cell and then find the average length of a hashtag? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Give us an example of what you think would be the best way to do this. (Hint: all hashtags will have the # character as their first char)

Comment: My cell is called lines so would it just be `regexp(lines,'/<#')`?

Comment: Have you tried this? Did it work?

Comment: That may work, I had strfind(lines,'#') in mind which will return an array of all the `#` occurances in lines for every cell. It seems like regexp does the same thing. After this you would need to find the space char following the chars after `#`.

Comment: What would I need to do after using strfind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, I think, with your `regexp` call. I will just clarify a few things. If you want the text in every hashtag in the tweet, you would want to use regexp to search for the pound sign (#) and include every character after that, until you reach the end of the word, e.g.

```
text = '#this #is a #test';
regexpi(lines,'\<#[a-z0-9_]*\>','match');
ans = 
    '#this'    '#is'    '#test'
```

where `regexpi` is a case-insensitive regexp, and the regex searches for '#' followed by a any number of letters, digits, or underscores (which are, I believe, the valid hashtag characters). The 'match' flag makes the `regexp` function return the actual matches.

If you don't want the actual hashtag in the final text, you could use regex look-behinds to return only the text. For instance:

```
regexpi(lines,'\<(?<=#)[a-z0-9_]*\>','match')
ans = 
    'this'    'is'    'test'
```

I think, technically, a hashtag must start with a letter, so this regex would return potentially invalid hashtags. It's not difficult to sort that out though.

Comment: Ok thank you! Now from here, would I be able to find the average length of each hashtag by using strcat?

Comment: I would personally use `cellfun`. If you use the regex above and store the result in a cell array called `hashtags`, you can find the length of each hashtag using `cellfun(@length,hashtags)`. For the example I gave above, this would give you `ans = [4 2 4]`. So, to find the average length, you would do something like `mean(cellfun(@length,hashtags))`.

Comment: But if my hashtags are in a cell would I have to concatenate them using strcat?

Comment: Not if you want the average length of each hashtag individually. If you concatenate them, how do you propose to get the average length of the tags?

Comment: True, but when I use `cellfun` to find the length, since the hashtags are each a column in a cell, it tells me how many columns are in the cell, not how long the hash tag is. Here is the code I am using: `hashtags=regexpi(lines,'\<#[a-z0-9_]*\>','match');
lengthht=cellfun(@length,hashtags)`

Comment: Try `lengthht=cellfun(@length,[hashtags{:}])` instead

Comment: Would I be able to exclude the "#" from the length calculation?

Comment: Use the second regex example in my answer to get the hashtags without the '#'.